# Rails console won't run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console

I seem to be having an issue starting the rails console. This is what happens when i do the bundle exec rails console:

```
neda@ubuntu:~/Documents/RailsProjects/vega$ bundle exec rails console
/home/neda/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:270: warning: circular argument reference - now
SECURITY WARNING: No secret option provided to Rack::Session::Cookie.
    This poses a security threat. It is strongly recommended that you
    provide a secret to prevent exploits that may be possible from crafted
    cookies. This will not be supported in future versions of Rack, and
    future versions will even invalidate your existing user cookies.
Called from: /home/neda/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:28:in `initialize'.
/home/neda/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- test/unit/testcase (LoadError)
from /home/neda/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /home/neda/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /home/neda/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /home/neda/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/test_case.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/neda/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /home/neda/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /home/neda/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /home/neda/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /home/neda/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/console/app.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/neda/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /home/neda/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /home/neda/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /home/neda/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /home/neda/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:299:in `initialize_console'
from /home/neda/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:152:in `load_console'
from /home/neda/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:27:in `start'
from /home/neda/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /home/neda/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: `cannot load such file -- test/unit/testcase (LoadError)` ---- Have you run `bundle install`?

Comment: @TomLord I am using Rails 3.2.6

Comment: run bundle install and then run rails console only

Comment: try running gem update --system on the console